# RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [3, 336, 500] at entry 0 and [3, 500, 336] at entry 1

Tags: pytorch

I am running AutoNovel code by Kai Han with ZSL datasets and ran into this error. I saw some similar questions but I am not sure how I can do it with 3 elements in the tensor. Is there a way to use transpose() or resize() for this issue?

Code:

```
def _load_function(idx):
idx = idx % len(self.dataset)
img0, _ = self.dataset[idx]
rotated_imgs = [
    self.transform(img0),
    self.transform(rotate_img(img0,  90).copy()),
    self.transform(rotate_img(img0, 180).copy()),
    self.transform(rotate_img(img0, 270).copy())
]
rotation_labels = torch.LongTensor([0, 1, 2, 3])
return torch.stack(rotated_imgs, dim=0), rotation_labels
```

Comment: Please provide some code with a minimal and reproducible example!

Comment: Is there a message function in this website? I am not sure where I can add the code you provided...

Comment: No there is no such function on StackOverflow. However, you can edit your question as much as needed. Even after users have posted their answers.

Comment: The error is caused at the last line that starts with "Return". Where can I add your "x = x.permute(0,2,1)"? Do I call it like rotation_labels = rotation_labels.permute(0,2,1)?

Comment: No try on `rotated_imgs`, that's the one throwing the error right (the input of `torch.stack`).

Comment: I got "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'permute'"

Comment: What shapes do your elements in `rotated_imgs` have?

Comment: It starts like this: [tensor([[[-0.4226, -0.4739, -0.3883,  ..., -0.4054, -0.4739, -0.4568],
         [-0.4911, -0.4911, -0.4568,  ..., -0.3883, -0.4226, -0.4226],
         [-0.4226, -0.3883, -0.3712,  ..., -0.3883, -0.3883, -0.3712],
         ...,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235024/discussion-between-chris-choi-and-ivan).

Comment: The shapes of those tensors please

Comment: I am really sorry. How can I find the shape of the tensors?

Comment: `print([t.shape for t in rotated_imgs])` should work

Comment: Before error:                                                                                          
[torch.Size([3, 328, 500]), torch.Size([3, 500, 328]), torch.Size([3, 328, 500]), torch.Size([3, 500, 328])]
[torch.Size([3, 336, 500]), torch.Size([3, 500, 336]), torch.Size([3, 336, 500]), torch.Size([3, 500, 336])]
[torch.Size([3, 333, 500]), torch.Size([3, 500, 333]), torch.Size([3, 333, 500]), torch.Size([3, 500, 333])]
[torch.Size([3, 375, 500]), torch.Size([3, 500, 375]), torch.Size([3, 375, 500]), torch.Size([3, 500, 375])]

Comment: After error: [torch.Size([3, 253, 380]), torch.Size([3, 380, 253]), torch.Size([3, 253, 380]), torch.Size([3, 380, 253])]. Sorry about bad formatting.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very wild guess but based on *`[3, 336, 500] vs [3, 500, 336]`*, I would suggest to permute axis 1 with axis 2.

```
>>> x = x.permute(0,2,1)
```